# Timely reminders using Nintex

Tags: sharepoint-2013, nintex-workflow

I am new to Nintex Workflows and trying to create Email reminders.
My Requirement is to send Reminder/Emails using Nintex. Let say I have 3 type of Email Reminder Templates R1, R2, R3 and Type of users as U1, U2 and U3.
I want to send R1 to U1 on every 1st business day of the month.
R2 to U2 to every 5th business day of the month.
and R3 to U3 on every 1st,2nd,3rd,4th and 5th business day of the month.
I know its bit difficult to calculate business day in nintex that's where I am struggling. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create site workflows and schedule them to run on 1st working day of the month.

First Working day of the month can be sent in regional setting of site.

Site Setting => under Site Administration.

Now the flow of the site workflow will be like

- Query list with U1 type users and save them in a workflow collection variable.
- Now use a collection operation and remove duplicates from the U1 type users collection.
- use for each action and iterate through the collection.
- use send reminder/notification action.

After that schedule site workflow to run on first working day of every month by navigating to

Site Content => Gear Icon At right top => Nintex Workflow => Schedule Site Workflow

Select start date and do check working day checkbox.